# Rails - Whenever gem - Dynamic values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rubygems, whenever

Lets say I have a cronjob like this:

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do  
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"  
end
```

Although, I would like to make '1.day' more dynamic, such as changing the value via a form in an administration page.

Then it could look like this:

```
every Constant.find(2).value, :at => '4:30 am' do
```

or

```
@const = Constant.find(2)
every @const.span, :at => @const.time do
```

Can anyone come up with an idea on how to make this work?

Obviously, the reason for this would be that I could use the values stored in the database on my site, like an message saying

```
<%= "The next update is in less than #{@const.time}" #or something similar %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never tried, but you should be able to do this by loading up the Rails environment in whenever so that you can use your model classes. Just use `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "./environment"` (or `"./application"` for Rails 3) in your schedule.rb, assuming your schedule.rb is in the config dir.

However, since all whenever does is generate lines in the crontab, any changes made to any `Constant` would require running `whenever --update-crontab` again.

Answer (score 10):

Thank you idlefingers! It totally worked. Here's my solution:

```
require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/environment.rb"

@notification_daily = Constant.find_by_key("notification_daily_time_span")
every eval(@notification_daily.value), :at => @notification_daily.additional_data do
  runner "Notification.daily"
end

@notification_weekly = Constant.find_by_key("notification_weekly_time_span")
every eval(@notification_weekly.value), :at => @notification_weekly.additional_data do
  runner "Notification.weekly"
end
```

.value can contain for example: **1.day** or **:sunday**
.additional_data contains the timestamp, example: **11:00am**

And yes, I'm aware that I need to run **--update crontab** again :)
But I'll let a cronjob update itself, hehe.

Comment: That doesn't work for me in Rails4. The require statement doesn't work. any idea what do I need to change?

Comment: I haven't tried Rails 4 myself yet, but i think RAILS_ROOT is changed to Rails.root.

Comment: @Frexuz : What is this line means, can you help me to get rid of it. notification_weekly = Constant.find_by_key("notification_weekly_time_span") - also what is notification_weekly_time_span

Comment: @SSR That is just my own model which I can change via my Admin UI. It's a model that has `value` and `additional_data` to be able to generate a Whenever row dynamically. You can fetch any data you want, as long as its value translates to any valid Whenever value. As stated in my answer: `.value` can contain for example: *1.day* or *:sunday*
`.additional_data` contains the timestamp, example: *11:00am*

Comment: @Frexuz Thanks for the information. but I am still confused how to achieve this one. can you help me? can you share your code or can you list steps?

Comment: If you read my question, the only thing I am doing is replaceing `1.day` and `4:30 am` inside `every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do` with variables from my application. Only difference is, that `1.day` is a string (from `@notification_daily.value`), so it need an `eval()` around it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you tell, please , what about "cronjob update itself"? How you finally achieve autoupdating?

Comment: Just create a normal cron job, that runs something like `cd your/app && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab`

Answer (score 7):

```
# In rails 4
require File.expand_path('../..//config/environment.rb', __FILE__)

# This is your table by which you will get your new value 
bid_update = DynamicOfferTime.first

# Now Task As
every (bid_update.hour_value).hours do
  puts "This will repeat in every #{bid_update.hour_value} hour"
end
```

## Do not forget to update whenever

Comment: I use rails 4 too, `require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/environment.rb"` works fine here.

Comment: Thanks, But I faced this issue and resolved by above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task and decided to solve it a bit another approach. 
In my table have a lot of records where storing settings for schedule
(daily, monthly, weekly, time)

In `schedule.rb` file I added a cron job, which was running every day at 00:00 and select the records, which can be run today. And after it added to queue with sidekiq using `perform_at`.