# To run periodic tasks with dynamic changing period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a task that is to monitor some information from  [stock website](http://money.cnn.com/quote/quote.html?symb=NFX).

It should check the stock status the website every **10 minute**,

Once if the stock index is rising, the check period should change to every **5 second**.

If the sotck index is downing, then the check period should be **10 minute**.

#### For running a periodic task

I found gem `whenever` can do cron task.
But I have no ideas to dynamically change the check period ?
any ideas ?

Comment: Can you describe your demand more detail? If you want to run task with different inverval, you can have two tasks and add more condition to check if need run.

Comment: For this simple task I would create _two_ different cron tasks and one, say, “global” variable, denoting whether the frequent task should be actually run. That way the per-10-mins task will be run always and per-5-secs task will be run if and only the index is rising.

Comment: Change task frequency dynamically, you can call `system('whenever --update-crontab .......')` when catch a change with your stock, then crontab will update to new frequency

Comment: you can also use any conditional in the whenever  block look this post it will clear your doubts  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602418/rails-whenever-gem-dynamic-values

Answer (score 1):

For this simple task I would create two different cron tasks and one, say, “global” variable, denoting whether the frequent task should be actually run. That way the per-10-mins task will be run always and per-5-secs task will be run if and only the index is rising.

```
class Checker
  @@rising = false
  class << self
    def check
      @@rising = actual_check > 0 # core check func
    end
    def freq_check
      check if @@rising
    end
    def rare_check
      check
    end
  end
end

every 10.minutes do
  runner "Checker.rare_check"
end
every 5.seconds do
  runner "Checker.freq_check"
end
```

This is definitely not a most elegant solution, but it does a trick and is really easy to handle/test.