# Run method periodically in manualy created interval in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I have a form when user can set day in week and time period (for example Monday from 02:00 to 03:00).
Then I want to run specific method (periodically, for example every 30 seconds) but only during given time interval (it should be performed on background every Monday during 02:00 and 03:00, every 30 seconds).
Is it possible to do this when time interval is created dynamically (by user)?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602418/rails-whenever-gem-dynamic-values

Comment: try using delayed_job gem in rails

Comment: You can use tools like rufus-scheduler https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a cron job which runs a rake task (refer to this for syntactic sugar: https://github.com/javan/whenever).
Your rake task could run every X seconds and query the database for new jobs.

However, calling a rake task via cron boots the rails app every time, so a more suffisticated approach would be to use sidekiq (http://sidekiq.org/) in combination with sidekiq-scheduler (https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler).