# Running a cron job at different times for each job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, whenever

I am building an application in rails that allows users to post products for sale for a set duration of time. Each product has a different 'end_time' in which I want to run a method that sets that updates the product status to 'dead'. 
I've been reading up on the Wheneverize gem, however as far as I can tell I would use it for doing a recurring task every minute, hour, day, etc...
Any ideas on how I would go about to running a cron job that would run at each product's specific 'end_time'?

for example something along the lines of:

```
live_products = Product.where('status = ?', 'live')

live_products.each do |product|
 at: product.end_time do
   product.status = 'dead'
   product.save
 end
end
```

Comment: look on this link.. may help you [stackoverflow.com/questions/4602418](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602418/rails-whenever-gem-dynamic-values/31075237#31075237)

Answer (score 0):

Cronjob, every minute, checking for those that need transaction to dead.

```
Product.turn_dead.update_all status: :dead 



#product.rb
scope :live, -> {where status: :live}
scope :out_of_time, -> {where "end_time <= ?", Time.now}
scope :turn_dead, ->{ live.out_of_time }
```